# Kentico - Show sibling document name on the parent repeater

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I got the following tree structure.

[image]

I have a repeater on Podcast page and need to display the latest sibiling document name on each item on the repeater. So for example, I will have the following in the repeater

- MHPN Presents Ageing Well -
  Latest: Episod 1
- MHPN Presents Trauma and Resilience -
  Latest: Trauma and Resilience: Trauma, a history

Answer (score 0):

You could use `webpart` within the transformation. Something like that could do what you want. You have to change the `ClassNames`, `SiteName`, `TransformationName` with the one you want. This `OrderBy` will display the first on the tree. You can change it accordingly if you want something else.

```xml
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CMSWebParts_Viewers_Documents_cmsrepeater"  Codebehind="~/CMSWebParts/Viewers/Documents/cmsrepeater.ascx.cs" %>
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="CMSRepeater1" runat="server" Path="./%" ClassNames="podcast.episode" SiteName="YourSite" TransformationName="podcast.episode.latest" TopN="1" OrderBy="NodeLevel, NodeOrder, NodeName" />
```

You can have a similar results using a Hierarchical viewer as well. However, since you require only one sibling you cannot do it that easily.

You can find an example at [xperience](https://docs.xperience.io/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/using-hierarchical-transformations) and [kentico](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/simplifying-your-hierarchical-viewers-with-the-sublevelplaceholder-control)

There might be small differences depending on the Kentico version you are using.

Dimitris